# Parallel for loop R

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I am calling a function inside a for loop.

```
sample_fun <- function(x,y) {
    # do something with x,y and return value
}

My loop looks like
result = list()

for(i in 1:10000)
   result[i] = sample_fun(i,i+1)
```

How do i parallelize this loop. Using foreach and dopar gives me subscript error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(doSNOW)

sample_fun <- function(x,y) {
  # do something with x,y and return value
}

threads <- 8
N <- 10000

cl <- makeCluster(threads)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

result <- foreach(i=1:N) %dopar% sample_fun(i,i+1)

stopCluster(cl)
```

http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parallel-computing-r-windows-using-dosnow-foreach/

Comment: Thanks joy. A 10% improvement in user time. ANy more aggressive approaches you would suggest. I am trying to process huge graphs using igraph package

Comment: Check out the link. The trick is to balance the size of each processing chunk handed to a thread propperly. With 8 cores I get an improvement of up to 450%. Also observe in your task manager what happens to the newly created R sessions - their CPU and RAM usage.